# How to Catch "Cant play this video" Error in Xamarin Android using setOnErrorListener

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, renderer, android-video-player

I want to catch error **"Can't Play this video"** by making **setOnErrorListener:** return **true** .

As the documentation says If no listener is specified, or if the listener returned false, Video View will inform the user of any errors., so I'm assuming if you set one and return true it will not show the user error.
I have seen some code in Java Android , But I am not that great with java.
I would appreciate if Some one can help me with Links in Xamarin or could explain me How to use it with working example.

Code in Android was like :

```
video.setOnErrorListener(new OnErrorListener()
{
    @Override
        public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra)
    {
        Log.d("video", "setOnErrorListener ");
        return true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this way by implementing `IOnErrorListener` interface

```
public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity, IOnErrorListener
{
    public bool OnError(MediaPlayer mp, [GeneratedEnum] MediaError what, int extra)
    {
        // Do Something here because error happened
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay so let me explain you current scenarion :
I have made a layout (In Xamarin Native ) and My Video is played in WebView Page in (Shared)

Comment: So This Function Should be in Main Activity ?

Comment: This is `Xamarin.Native` only. Not only activities, you can use in fragments too.

Comment: I had made a Message Renderer inheriting ViewCellRenderer which decides what template to Choose . So in Video Template Should I make this call ?

Comment: I am encountering this error :---CustomRenderer.MessageRenderer` 
implements `Android.Runtime.IJavaObject`
 but does not inherit `Java.Lang.Object` or `Java.Lang.Throwable`. This is not supported.

Comment: I tried to inherit Java.Lang.Throwable but it says can't have multiple base classes  ViewCellRenderer  and Java.Lang.Throwable.

Comment: any  idea how to fix ?

Comment: Your class should't be concrete class. It should be Activity or Fragment, which is getting inherit from `Java.Lang.Object`.

Comment: Okay. Need to figure this out then . Well Thanks